# в языке си отсутствует проблема с вычислением переменных с плавающей точкой?

Tags: javascript, c

Возник такой вопрос. При работе в языке си я не наблюдаю проблемы при вычислении переменных с плавающей точкой. В java и javascript при такой же операции возникает погрешность.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: действительно ли в си не возникает погрешностей и если да, то почему так? В чём тут подвох?

[image: Си]

[image: javascript]

Comment: Подвох в том, что `printf` по умолчанию округляет вывод до шести знаков после точки.

Comment: Ну, и если [вывести больше знаков](https://rextester.com/HXPA19584), то станет понятно, что 1) в C также присутствую особенности арифметики с плавающей точкой, 2) `console.log` также округляет вывод.

Comment: Пооонял, спасибо!

Comment: `printf("%.12f",1.0f/3.0f);` -> `0.333333343267`